# Make gcc/g++ use absolute path for warnings when compiling files in pwd

Tags: gcc, g++

Is there a way to make gcc use the absolute path when printing errors found in files compiled in the current directory?

For instance the following does what I want when print errors:

```
g++ -I. -I../../.. /home/some/path/somefile.cpp
```

but I want to achieve the same with something like:

```
g++ -I. -I../../.. somefile.cpp
```

I want warnings and errors to be formatting something like:

```
/home/some/path/somefile.cpp:299:52: warning: some warning
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this with gcc itself, but it's trivial with a wrapper script, installed as "gcc", "g++", etc in a directory before `/usr/bin` in your PATH:

```sh
#! /bin/sh
sourcefile="$1"; shift
case "$sourcefile" in
    /*) ;;
    *) sourcefile="$PWD/$sourcefile" ;;
esac
exec "/usr/bin/${0##*/}" "$sourcefile" "$@"
```

... provided that you always put the source file *first* in your compiler invocation (you'll have to tweak your Makefiles).

Comment: This would break horribly if $1 is an absolute path, or if $1 is "-I." (as it is in the question).

Comment: I did say you must always put the source file first.  Good point about $1 being an absolute path, though, I'll fix that.